# Java error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, compiler-errors, javac

I need to know the output of this code. But it's not working. Maybe the code is wrong.
I'm still learning how to use Java, and I tried fixing this for hours but still no luck.

Here is the code:

```
public class A 
{ 
    public A() 
    {
        System.out.println ("A");
    }
}
public class B extends A 
{
    public B() 
    {
        System.out.println ("B");
    }
}
public class C extends B 
{ 
    public C() 
    {
        System.out.println ("C");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    A a = new A();  
    B b = new B();  
    C c = new C();  
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong or missing in the code?

Comment: The "output" of the code is that it's invalid code. Your `main` method isn't inside a class. Methods *must* be in classes - what class did you expect it to be in? Note that if you formatted your code more conventionally, the error would be easier to see.

Comment: Try indenting your code and putting your braces on separate lines. You'll find the problem in no time.

Comment: Also you can't have more than one public class in a single file. And the file name must be same as the public class name.

Comment: Each public class must be in its own file named same as the class itself. is it fullfilled? Btw place here compiler error as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String...args) {
        new C();
    }

    public static class A {
        public A() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }
    public static class B extends A {
        public B() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }
    public static class C extends B {
        public C() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that this might not print what you would expect. It would actually print:

```
A
B
C
```

Why? Constructors are always chained to the super class.

Answer (score 5):

Put your main method in a class.

```
Filename : DemoClass.java

class A 
{ 
    public A() 
    {
        System.out.println ("A");
    }
}
class B extends A 
{
    public B() 
    {
        System.out.println ("B");
    }
}
class C extends B 
{ 
    public C() 
    {
        System.out.println ("C");
    }
}

public class DemoClass {

   public static void main(String args[]) {

       A a = new A();  
       B b = new B();  
       C c = new C();  
   }
}
```

Another point here is, you can have only public class in a file, so your `A` `B` and `C` all class can't be `public` in same java file.

Your java file name must be same as public class name. i.e. here `DemoClass` is public class so file name will be `DemoClass.java`

Java doc for getting started : [getting started with java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html.)

Answer (score 0):

You can, but it is not recommended, nest your classes in a file. It is perfectly valid.

Notice in the output below that each successive child calls its parent's default constructor (`super()`) implicitly.

I recommend you create the files: `A.java`, `B.java`, `C.java`, and `InheritenceTest.java`.

```
public class InheritenceTest {
    public class A {
        public A() {
            System.out.println("A");
        }
    }

    public class B extends A {
        public B() {
            System.out.println("B");
        }
    }

    public class C extends B {
        public C() {
            System.out.println("C");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        InheritenceTest i = new InheritenceTest();
        A a = i.new A();
        B b = i.new B();
        C c = i.new C();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
A
B
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning:
You shouldn't have more than 1 public classes in 1 java file, not recommended. However, it could still work if you didn't use the 'public' identifier (or by using static or inside another class). But for a starter, I would recommend you to have them all in separate files.

Error: 
Your main method does not belong to any class. I propose you create another class that includes the public static void main method to test your application.

Info: keep a look at inheritance as your printings might not be what you expect. (Constructor of class B calls the constructor of A, and constructor of class C calls the constructor B which in turn calls the constructor of A).

That's why you get

```
A
A  
B
A
B
C

*due to A() it prints A, then due to B() it prints A B and finally due to C() it prints A B C.
```

In your case, I would try the following:

```
//Filename: A.java
public class A { 
    public A() {
        System.out.println ("A");
    }
}
```

---

```
//Filename: B.java
public class B extends A { 
    public B() {
        System.out.println ("B");
    }
}
```

---

```
//Filename: C.java
public class C extends B { 
    public C() {
        System.out.println ("C");
    }
}
```

---

```
//Filename: Test.java
//use a Test class for testing
public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       A a = new A();  
       B b = new B();  
       C c = new C();  
   }
}
```