# error: class, interface, or enum expected

Tags: java, enums

I have the following code that I am trying to get working for a project in a class that I am in. I will also include the requirements

Design and implement the class Day that implements the day of the week in a program.  The class Day should store the day, such as Sun for Sunday.  The program should be able to perform the following operations on an object of type Day:

A. Set the day.

B. Print the day.

C. Return the day.

D. Return the next day.

E. Return the previous day.

F. Calculate and return the day by adding certain days to the current day.  For example, if the current day is Monday and we add four days, the day to be returned is Friday.  Similarly, if today is Tuesday and we add 13 days, the day to be returned is Monday.

G. Add the appropriate constructors.

H. Write the definitions of the methods to implement the operations for the class Day, as defined in A through G.

I. Write a program to test various operations on the class Day.

The code is as follows:

```
`import java.util.*;


class Day {
private int dayValue;
private static final int INVALID = -1;
public Day() { this.dayValue = INVALID; }
public Day(String day) { setDay(day); }
public Day(int day) { this.dayValue = (day<0 || day>6) ? INVALID : day; }
public void setDay(String day) {
    if(day.equals("sunday") || day.equals("Sun")) {
        this.dayValue = 0;
    } else if(day.equal("monday") || day.equals("Mon")) {
        this.dayValue = 1;
    } else if(day.equals("tuesday") || day.equals("Tues")) {
        this.dayValue = 2;
    } else if(day.equal("wednesday") || day.equals("Wed")) {
        this.dayValue = 3;
    } else if(day.equals("thursday") || day.equals("Thurs")) {
        this.dayValue = 4;
    } else if(day.equal("friday") || day.equals("Fri")) {
        this.dayValue = 5;
    } else if(day.equal("saturday") || day.equals("Sat")) {
        this.dayValue = 6;
    } else {
        this.dayValue = INVALID;
    }
}

public String getDay() {
    if (dayValue==0) { return "Sunday"; }
    if (dayValue==1) { return "Monday"; }
    if (dayValue==2) { return "Tuesday"; }
    if (dayValue==3) { return "Wednesday"; }
    if (dayValue==4) { return "Thursday"; }
    if (dayValue==5) { return "Friday"; }
    if (dayValue==6) { return "Saturday"; }

    return "\"I don't know what day it is!\"";

}
public void printDay() {
    System.out.println("When printing, your day is " + getDay()); //displays the day at the time of printing.
}
// Next Day
public String getNextDay()
  {
     // the compareTo() method allows us to set saturday as Sat, Sunday to Sun, etc
     if((day.compareTo("sunday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Sun") == 0))
        return ("Monday");
     else if((day.compareTo("monday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Mon") == 0))
        return ("Tuesday");
     else if((day.compareTo("tuesday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Tue") == 0))
        return ("Wednesday");
     else if((day.compareTo("wednesday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Wed") == 0))
        return ("Thursday");
     else if((day.compareTo("thursday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Thu") == 0))
        return ("Friday");
     else if((day.compareTo("friday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Fri") == 0))
        return ("Saturday");
     else if((day.compareTo("saturday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Sat") == 0))
        return ("Sunday");
     else
        return ("\"I don't know what day it is!\"");
  }
  // Previous day
  public String getPreDay()
  {
     if((day.compareTo("sunday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Sun") == 0))
        return ("Saturday");
     else if((day.compareTo("saturday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Sat") == 0))
        return ("Friday");
     else if((day.compareTo("friday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Fri") == 0))
        return ("Thursday");
     else if((day.compareTo("thursday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Thu") == 0))
        return ("Wednesday");
     else if((day.compareTo("wednesday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Wed") == 0))
        return ("Tuesday");
     else if((day.compareTo("tuesday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Tue") == 0))
        return ("Monday");
     else if((day.compareTo("monday") == 0) || (day.compareTo("Mon") == 0))
        return ("Sunday");
        return ("\"I don't know what day it is!\"");
  }
public Day calcDay(int offset) { /* your code here */ }
// extra good for printin
public String toString() { return getDay(); }
}


  // main execution point
 public static void main (String args[]) {
  {
   // One of its weakness is the case sensitive: sun, Sunday, sunday, SuNdAy...
   // need more codes to avoid this case sensitiveness...

   // instantiate testday object of type MyDay class
     // with "Sun" as initial value....
     Day testday = new Day("Sun");
     // prompt user to set his/her day
     System.out.print("Enter day to set your day: ");
     // read and store user's day
     String storeday = readinput.nextLine().toLowerCase(); //Changes input into all lowercase to deal with variations
     // invoke setDay() method to set a day defined by user
     testday.setDay(storeday);
     // invoke getDay() method to get a day
     System.out.println("Your day is " + testday.getDay());
     // test printing by invoking printDay() method
     testday.printDay();
     // invoke getPreDay() method to get the previous day
     System.out.println("Your previous day is " + testday.getPreDay());
     // invoke getNextDay() method to get the next day
     System.out.println("Your next day is " + testday.getNextDay());

     System.out.println("How many Days would you like to add? " + testday.calcNextDay());
  }


}`
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Day.java:92: error: class, interface, or enum expected
     public static void main () {

                   ^
Day.java:101: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         System.out.print("Enter day to set your day: ");

         ^
Day.java:103: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         String storeday = readinput.nextLine().toLowerCase(); //Changes input into all lowercase to deal with variations
         ^
Day.java:105: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         testday.setDay(storeday);
         ^
Day.java:107: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         System.out.println("Your day is " + testday.getDay());
         ^
Day.java:109: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         testday.printDay();
         ^
Day.java:111: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         System.out.println("Your previous day is " + testday.getPreDay());
         ^
Day.java:113: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         System.out.println("Your next day is " + testday.getNextDay());
         ^
Day.java:115: error: class, interface, or enum expected
         System.out.println("How many Days would you like to add? " + testday.calcNextDay());
         ^
Day.java:116: error: class, interface, or enum expected
      }
      ^
10 errors
```

Originally my code looked like this

`public class Day
    {
      static Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);

      String day;
      public Day(String day)
      {
         day = "Sunday";
      }
      // set the day
      public void setDay(String theDay)
      {
         day = theDay;
      }
      public String getDay()
      {
         return day;
      }
      public void printDay()
      {
         System.out.println("When printing, your day is " + day);
      }`

Comment: your code has major issues

Comment: what you wanna do ? you got everything wrong

Comment: Some of the problems: "day.equal" should be "day.equals".  The getNextDay() and getPreDay() methods are probably expecting the string argument day (similar to the setDay(String) method)?

Comment: The first big error you've got is that `main` needs to be inside the `Day` class.  Under your `toString` definition, there's a line with a right curly brace.  This is seen by the compiler as being the end of the `Day` class, and therefore `main` is a method outside of any class, which is going to lead to lots of compile-time errors that don't necessarily tell you what the real problem is.  Fix that first.  I.e. get rid of that curly brace.

Comment: Sorry there is no intention to put you down or criticize you, yet your code and your logic is messy

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will fix the main and day one now.

Comment: The task was to ask user for the day, then print the day they entered, the next day, the prior day and then ask how many days to add, and then show the day after that number of days was added. One of the requirements was that the days must be stored as Sun, Mon, etc (strings) and not as numbers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java error: class, interface, or enum expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699574/java-error-class-interface-or-enum-expected)

Answer (score 2):

**Why not use arrays?**

With an array, you could handle things in a more concise and simple way.

```
String[] dayOfWeekShortNames = new String[] { 
    "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" 
};

String[] dayOfWeekLongNames = new String[] {
    "Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
};
```

Then, simply validate whether the value passed in parameter is correct.

```
public void setDay(String dayOfWeek) {
    if (dayOfWeek == null || (0 < dayOfWeek.length() && dayOfWeek.trim().length() == 0))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("dayOfWeek cannot be null or white space.");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < dayOfWeek.length(); i++)
        if (dayOfWeek.charAt(i).isDigit()) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("dayOfWeek cannot be numeric.");

    if (dayOfWeek.length() < 3) // for short names
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("dayOfWeek must be at least 3 characters long.");

    for (int i = 0; i < dayOfWeekShortNames.length && i < dayOfWeekLongNames.length; i++)
        if (dayOfWeekShortNames[i].toLowerCase() == dayOfWeek.ToLowerCase()
            || dayOfWeekLongNames[i].toLowerCase() == dayOfWeek.ToLowerCase()) {
            dayValue = i;
            return;
        }        

    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Day of week: " + dayOfWeek + " could not be found.");
}
```

This is just a simple example off the top of my head.

**Why not use a Program class?**

Instead of just writing the `main()` method out of nowhere which can lead to multiple compile-time errors, perhaps one great deal would be to locate your `main` method inside a `Program` class so that it is a member of a class, and the compiler shall no longer complaint. Furthermore, the advantage of doing so shall make it obvious, at least at some extent, that your program entry point is there. This `Program` class shall contain nothing more than the `main()` method.

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // You code here...
    }
}
```

As for the user inputs, perhaps using the `Console` class... Here's an example on how to use it.

- [**I/O from the Command Line**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html)

> **Disclaimer**
>
> *I have not tested this code and is provided as-is for example purposes only. I am not a Java expert, and I did my best off the top of my head to help.*

**EDIT**

> **I did not use an array because I wanted to store the value as a string and not the index.**

In fact, the code sample in your question stores the day of week in an integer value as per this line:

```
private int dayValue;
```

Hence the assignments when you set the day as follows:

```
public void setDay(String day) {
    if (day == "sunday" || day == "Sun")
        dayValue = 0;
    else if (day == "monday" || day == "Mon")
        dayValue = 1;
    ...
}
```

The above actually stores the day of week in an integer format which shall satisfy most of any systems which is going to use days of week. Plus, you cannot guarantee the exact syntax of a string input by the user so that even if you either compare `day == "sunday"` or `day == "Sun"`, you would have to adjust your casing according to the string you're expecting in your `setDay()` function, which in my opinion doesn't make sense.

The most common practice for such behaviour playing around with days of week, etc. is to use arrays with the proper expected casing, then compare the input values with either uppercase or lowercase values for both, the input and the value from the array (only this can guarantee a perfect match), then you can store the index in you `dayValue` private member. Then, when retrieving the day of week through the `getDay()` function, you can simply write a single line of code which can assure you to work flawlessly, since you captured any potential errors while setting the input through the `setDay()` method.

```
public String getDay() { return dayOfWeekLongNames[dayValue]; }
```

And you shall get the name of the day of week previously set, instead of having to write `if statements` over and over again.

Comment: I did not use an array because I wanted to store the value as a string and not the index.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach the problem is to use an enum for the days of the week.  Here's a working example provided to show the general idea:

```
public class Day
{
    enum DAY {
        MONDAY("Monday"), TUESDAY("Tuesday"), WEDNESDAY("Wednesday"), THURSDAY("Thursday"), FRIDAY("Friday"), SATURDAY(
            "Saturday"), SUNDAY("Sunday");

        public static DAY parse(final String value)
        {
            for (final DAY day : values())
            {
                if (day.description.equalsIgnoreCase(value) || day.description.substring(0, 3).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
                {
                    return day;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String description;

        private DAY(final String description)
        {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return description;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String args[])
    {
        Day myDay;

        myDay = new Day(DAY.SUNDAY);

        System.out.println(myDay);
        System.out.println(myDay.getPreviousDay());
        System.out.println(myDay.getNextDay());

        myDay = new Day("monday");

        System.out.println(myDay);
        System.out.println(myDay.getPreviousDay());
        System.out.println(myDay.getNextDay());

        myDay = new Day("wed");

        System.out.println(myDay);
        System.out.println(myDay.getPreviousDay());
        System.out.println(myDay.getNextDay());
    }

    private final DAY day;

    public Day(final DAY day)
    {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public Day(final String day)
    {
        this.day = DAY.parse(day);
    }

    public DAY getNextDay()
    {
        final DAY[] days = DAY.values();
        return days[(day.ordinal() + 1) % days.length];
    }

    public DAY getPreviousDay()
    {
        final DAY[] days = DAY.values();
        return days[((day.ordinal() - 1) + days.length) % days.length];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return day.toString();
    }
}
```